# Define a scheme procedure

Tags: scheme

I need helpwriting a scheme procedure that takes two lists as inputs and the outputs an indication as to whether list2 is less than list1.

```
(define (analyze list1 list2
```

Comment: What does it mean for one list to be "less than" another list? Shorter length? Some kind of sort order?

Comment: And what is your question? Surely you don't expect a solution, as then you wouldn't have been doing your homework?

Comment: May i ask what language this is about? that it is a scheme i can see but ...

Comment: @Mythje: Scheme is a Lisp dialect. It's used a lot by academics to teach programming fundamentals.

Comment: @nmichaels Aha then they forgot to teach me that lol or prehaps under a other name then.

Answer (score 1):

Definition:

```
(define (analyze list1 list2)
  (< (length list1) (length list2)))
```

Usage:

```
(analyze (list 1) (list 2 3)) -> #t
```